# CSS button with slash line decoration

Tags: html, css

I would like to create HTML/CSS (with no image file) button of the box with slash lines decoration.
Attached is the sample image.

I've seen the CSS tricks to draw diagonal line, but couldn't find the one for this kind of multiple diagonal lines.

Can anyone help me on this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the angle :

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  45deg,
  #606dbc,
  #606dbc 10px,
  #465298 10px,
  #465298 20px
);
```

**[Source](http://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/)**

Comment: Thanks Ben. Your comment and the link helped me. The link page suggests that I should have searched with the keywords of "stripes" "repeating" to get to know this background: repeating-linear-gradient().

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you could use a repeating CSS gradient background and then have an inner div with the blue background to mask out the diagonal lines.

Comment: Thanks Jason, after use the background: repeating-linear-gradient() method and mask with a layer with inner div, it worked!